# How to revert back changes in gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle

So I was debugging locally installed gems:

```
/Users/myUser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@12wbt-engine/gems/locomotive_liquid-2.4.2
```

And now I removed the this folder. Hence I'm wondering if there is any way to restore it?

DOESN'T WORK:

```
bundle install
bundle update
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
gem uninstall locomotive_liquid
bundle install
```

Answer (score 11):

What you need is [gem pristine](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem_pristine)

e.g:

```
gem pristine locomotive_liquid
```